# How to get Parcable Bundle from Activity in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, parcelable

I have written following code in my Activity Class,

```
ArrayList<TXData> data;
data= Map.getDataList();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data",data);

Fragment fragment = new MapsFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

In `MapsFragment`, I have written following code to get data on `onActivityCreated()` Method.

```
ArrayList<TXData> dataList;

dataList=getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("data");
```

It returns following exception on Fragment class.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method java.util.ArrayList
>   android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String) on a null
>   object reference

I added debug points, to find out the cause of problem, It successfully adds the data to Bundle from `Activity`, but its not getting any data in Fragment.

Kindly guide me what I am doing wrong here.

**EDIT**
**Parceable Class**

```
public class TXData implements Serializable, Parcelable{

    public String id;
    public String title;
    public String pId = "";
    public float heading;
    public float pitch;
    public int totalCount;
    int mData;

    public TXSData(){

    }


    protected TXData(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readString();
        title = in.readString();
        pId = in.readString();
        heading = in.readFloat();
        pitch = in.readFloat();
        totalCount = in.readInt();
        mData = in.readInt();
        minPrice = in.readInt();
        maxPrice = in.readInt();
        isInFilter = in.readByte() != 0;
        isEnabled = in.readByte() != 0;
        totalCount = in.readInt();
    }




    public static final Creator<TXData> CREATOR = new Creator<TXData>() {
        @Override
        public TXData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new TXData(in);
        }

        @Override
        public TXData[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TXData[size];
        }
    };



    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mData);

    }
```

Comment: TXData can you show this class in the question?

Comment: Have u tried it in `onCreateView` ?

Comment: @SurajRao : I have updated my question. 
@ρяσѕρєяK : Yes, onCreateView called before the Activity onCreate completes its work, so it was failing to add data to the bundle. whereas, `onActivityCreated` successfully adds data to the  Bundle

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution would be to drop the Parcelable and stay with Serializable.

```
    public class TXData implements Serializable{

    public String id;
    public String title;
    public String pId = "";
    public float heading;
    public float pitch;
    public int totalCount;
    int mData;
}
```

and use `putExtra/getSerializableExtera` instead of `getParcelableArrayList/setParcelableArrayList`

For big amounts of data, it is recommended to use Parcelable which is built for speed, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-parcelable) or similar...

Comment: bundle.putExtra is not there.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace below class.**

```
public class TXData implements Parcelable {

    public String id;
    public String title;
    public String pId = "";
    public float heading;
    public float pitch;
    public int totalCount;
    int mData;

    public TXSData(){

    }



    protected TXData(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readString();
        title = in.readString();
        pId = in.readString();
        heading = in.readFloat();
        pitch = in.readFloat();
        totalCount = in.readInt();
        mData = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(pId);
        dest.writeFloat(heading);
        dest.writeFloat(pitch);
        dest.writeInt(totalCount);
        dest.writeInt(mData);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<TXData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<TXData>() {
        @Override
        public TXData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new TXData(in);
        }

        @Override
        public TXData[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TXData[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the Bundle object (`getArguments()`) in `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`
 of the fragment and not `onActivityCreated()`.

Refer to the example from [Fragment documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try that.

```
ArrayList<TXData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

dataList.addAll(getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("data"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your writeToParcel method is incomplete.
Your writeToParcel should be writing all the properties in the same order as it is in the parameterized contructor: `protected TXSectionData(Parcel in)`

Check here: [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable)

> One very important thing to pay close attention to is the order that you write and read your values to and from the Parcel. They need to match up in both cases. The mechanism that Android uses to read the Parcel is blind and completely trusts you to get the order correct, or else you will run into run-time crashes.